# Printing support for Windows Mobile

Tags: printing, windows-mobile, windows-ce

I'm a windows developer looking for implementation of priting support for Windows Mobile 6.5.

As the WM6.5 is based on the Windows CE 5.0, I have gone through the architecture of Printing in Windows CE and what I have realized from the Windows CE Printer architecture is :

For a USB class printer the main components required  for printing in Windows CE apart from Display driver and GDI components would be :

Printer driver                 :  PCL.dll

The underliying  port driver for USB class driver  : USBPRN.dll

These components' source code exist in the driver samples provided by the WinCE 5.0 platform builder.

Though these components exist no third parties (ex: PrintBoy,PrintCE ) seems to be utilising them.

My Queries are:
1.Can I use the Microsoft supplied source code of these compenents as it is to support Printing in Windows Mobile?

2.According to Microsoft's Shared source License agreement,are there any source code usage viaolation if I use them?

3.Can I use the source code of PCL and USBPRN to support in Windows Mobile as it is? or do I need to modify it?

(I assume Windows Mobile have GDI and Display driver components by default.)

- Thanks.
  Sree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I Don't believe WinMo includes the printer pieces for CE.
2. I'm not a lawyer (nor do I play one on TV) but my interpretation is that you can't take the pieces from Platform Builder and use them in your WinMo OS.  You are licensed to modify them if you need and use them in your own custom OS.
3. See #2.  PCL would probably work as-is, but I'm guessing the USB printer driver might need at least some configuration work for your platform.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply.